# How to update event time in Google calendar from Google sheet by event name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I have a number of Futsal(indoor soccer) teams and am trying to make managing the calendar really easy.

Currently I pull the game details into a spreadsheet using an IMPORTHTML function with a query attached, then sort the data to process either by team or can do all teams at once.
All import sheets are set up with the same configuration to keep it simple.
Calendar ID is in B3
Start date and time is from B5:B100
End date and time is from C5:C100
The game name title from D5:D100 (displayed like "Cunning Stunts ✰✰ vs Borussia Dropkicks ☆✰")

Very rarely does the team change however the times can be adjusted throughout the season and I'd like to run the script and update the appointment time.

I can import games into the calendar without any problem as I've worked that bit out but cannot get my head around changing the time of an entry based on the event name.

I have tried a large amount of trial and error using other people questions around getId() functions and also if/else but I can only create duplicate events.

I'm fairly fresh to this world but am eager to continue learning and don't give up easily so any help would be appreciated.

Here is what I have working so far.

```
function gameImport() {
  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("b3").getValue();
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var calendarName = cal.getName();

  Browser.msgBox("Export Calendar = " + calendarName); 

  var games = spreadsheet.getRange("A5:D100").getValues();
  
  for (x=0; x<games.length; x++) {
    var details = games[x];
    
    var startTime = new Date(details[1]); //Start date and time
    var endTime = new Date(details[2]);  //End date and time
    var title = details[3];  //Game title

 cal.createEvent(title,startTime,endTime);
 

 Browser.msgBox("Great Sucess"); 

  }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ! Did you try those solutions ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005699/how-do-i-modify-a-google-calendar-event-using-google-apps-script

Comment: Yep, but also this involves an event ID that I'm not currently storing, ideally the process as automated as possible and this will create issues as an event id will not update when the imported timetable does.
This is why changing it by name is important.

Comment: Name could change, ID will not. Is there any specific reason you don't you want to store ID and update event by them?

Comment: TY @WaximCorp as this is for sports teams sometimes the time changes as games are moved around to suit different teams, these changes happen mostly early in the season. 
I want to look by name so I don't need to manually edit the spreadsheet for each team each season, I just need to run the script to push updates to the calendar and edit the entries.
Currently, the HTML import and queries etc automate everything for me the only manual step is running the script, although it creates duplicate events and this is the last part I'm trying to fix I hope that makes sense, thanks for the help.